# Why this code is creating two similar object in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

**Node js**

The method used to post the comment data

```
const { type, movieId, userId, review, timestamp } = req.body;

const movie = await Movie.findOneAndUpdate(
  { movieId: movieId, type: type },
  {
    $push: {
      movieReview: { ... },
    },
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true },
  (err, info) => {
    ...
  }
);
```

**Reactjs**

The method used to submit the comment

```
const submit_comment = async () => {
  ....
  const file = {
    movieId: id,
    type: type,
    userId: userInfo._id,
    comment: comment,
  };
  if (!commentFlag) {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/movie/add-comment", file, config);
    
  ...
};
```

**Mongoose Schema**

```
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  movieId: String,
  type: String,
  ...
  comment: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment" }],
});
```

After I run my submit function it posts two objects with the same object _id in mongoDB

Comment: Could you check the indexes of collection?

Comment: Whether the problem is that your code is sending the two calls on clicking submit or MongoDB is creating duplicate objects on clicking submit?

Comment: Both of the document have same index